# How to run embedded exe in new process from a published ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-services, exe

I want to run ntrights.exe from my website. To do this I am adding ntrights.exe as an embedded resource in my project and then at runtime the code extracts all of the bits to a new file called tempFile.exe, creates a new process using this exe, & runs it.

Here is what the code looks like to run ntrights.exe:

```
public void GiveLogOnAsAServiceRights(string server, LoginInfo credentials)
{
    string tempPathForExe = "C:\\Websites\\MyWebAppDirectory";
    string ntRightsTempFileName = "tempfile.exe";
    string fullNtRightsTempPath = Path.Combine(tempPathForExe, ntRightsTempFileName);

    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPathForExe);
    //Resource below is a resx file. ntrights is the ntrights.exe file I want to execute. It is an embedded resource.
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullNtRightsTempPath, Resource.ntrights);

    Process objProcess = new Process();
    objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fullNtRightsTempPath;
    //These args grant the provided user log on as a service rights on the given server
    objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " +r SeServiceLogonRight -u " + credentials.Domain + "\\" + credentials.Username + " -m \\\\" + server;
    objProcess.StartInfo.Domain = "myDomain";
    objProcess.StartInfo.UserName = "myUsername";
    objProcess.StartInfo.Password = ToSecureString("myPassword");
    objProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    objProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    objProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    objProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Websites\\MyWebAppDirectory";

    string connectionString = string.Empty;

    //During these next two functions, a console is supposed to pop up and tell me what it is doing... but it doesn't
    objProcess.Start();
    objProcess.WaitForExit();

    if (objProcess.HasExited)
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(fullNtRightsTempPath);
        objProcess.Close();
        return;
    }
}
```

**And this works great** & I see a window & output & it works successfully!... as long as I'm using F5 in Visual Studio to run it on IIS express. **The problem is that when I right click the project & click "publish" and publish to a local directory where a full IIS website is set up, then the executable no longer runs.** When debugging there is no window created or output.

How have I troubleshooted so far?

**(1)** I tried referencing the file directly by including it in the build output & using Appdomain.CurrentDomain.CurrentDirectory and finding the path of the exe & running it that way. This did not fix the problem.

**(2)** Making sure load user profile was set to true in IIS and making sure my user profile has explicit full control permissions on the folder the website is in. This did not fix the problem.

**(3)** Redirected StandardOutput and StandardError of the new process to read the output text of the new process. The output was an empty string.

**(4)** Updated the working directory to be the current directory that the exe is written to. This did not change the result.

I understand that running an exe from my web app is not the best idea, but nonetheless this is the way it needs to be done. It works when I just run the code from Visual Studio, so I'm guessing there is a way to get this working in IIS. Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Is it running then closing right away? You could put a log message inside `if (objProcess.HasExited)` to know if it's running but closing immediately. I see a lot of programs that will not run correctly and will crash if their working directory is not set, so I would try `objProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Websites\\MyWebAppDirectory"`. edit: not that it's "not set", it's that the process inherits a working directory that's different than where the .exe is so it can't find resources and crashes.

Comment: It does close immediately. I'll double check that when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: I tried setting the working directory to the same directory the exe is in, but the result is the same. The process exits almost immediately & there is no window or output.